# How to test hooks for custom module in PHPUnit kernel tests

Tags: hooks, testing

I have a custom module file that has one hook:

**mymodule.module:**

```
function mymodule_node_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {
  if (isset($node->original)) {
    $orig_node = $node->original;
    if($orig_node->hasField('field_intro')) {
      if ($orig_node->get('field_intro')->value !== $node->get('field_intro')->value) {
        $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser()->getUsername();
        Drupal::logger('mymodule')->notice('Lead changed from @original to @new', [
          '@original' => $orig_node->get('field_intro')->value,
          '@new' => $node->get('field_intro')->value,
          '@nid' => $node->id(),
          '@user' => $current_user,
        ]);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

And I am trying to test that this works in a PHPUnit kernel test like so:

**MyModuleKernelTest.php**

```
protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->installSchema('dblog', 'watchdog');
    $this->installEntitySchema('node');
    $this->installEntitySchema('user');

    $fieldIntroMock = $this->getMockBuilder(FieldItemListInterface::class)
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
    $fieldIntroMock->expects($this->any())
      ->method('__get')
      ->with('value')
      ->willReturn('hello');

    $this->node = $this->getMockBuilder(Node::class)
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();

    $this->node->expects($this->any())
      ->method('id')
      ->willReturn(1);

    $this->node->expects($this->any())
      ->method('__get')
      ->with('field_intro')
      ->willReturn($fieldIntroMock);
  }

 /**
   * Test pre-save hook.
   */
  public function testPresave() {
    $this->node->set('field_intro', 'hello world');
    $storage = $this->createMock('\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface');
    $this->node->preSave($storage);
    $pgsql_connection = Database::getConnection();
    $result = $pgsql_connection->select('watchdog', 'w')
      ->fields('w', ['type', 'variables', 'timestamp'])
      ->condition('type', 'mymodule')
      ->execute();

    $this->assertCount(1, $result);
  }
```

However the query above continually gives back a count of 0. Is there some configuration I am missing to allow for the presave hook to fire on saving the mock node?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not attach `use NodeCreationTrait;` to your kernel test and use `createNode` and the save() method? Is your module being required in the test?

Comment: @Kevin I am requiring the module in my test in the `$modules` static variable, and I have attached `NodeCreationTrait`, however when I call `createNode` it gives this error with the module: `Error: Call to a member function id() on boolean /var/www/drupalvm/web/core/modules/filter/filter.module:214`, thoughts?

Comment: Fixed this issue using `$this->installConfig(['field', 'node', 'text', 'filter', 'user']);` in the setUp function. Running into issues with the custom field `field_intro` however: `InvalidArgumentException: Field field_intro is unknown.` Wondering how to mock this?

Comment: You would need to provide configuration to support the test as well. Typically a module that has configuration is used for testing.